# Scada-Lts - 'No DataSource specified' error

Tags: java, tomcat, scada, scadalts

I tried to run Scada-Lts on Tomcat 7 with jdk 1.7 and i got the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.serotonin.mango.MangoContextListener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:97)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:382)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:428)
at com.serotonin.mango.db.MySQLAccess.newDatabaseCheck(MySQLAccess.java:76)
at com.serotonin.mango.db.DatabaseAccess.initialize(DatabaseAccess.java:118)
at com.serotonin.mango.MangoContextListener.databaseInitialize(MangoContextListener.java:391)
at com.serotonin.mango.MangoContextListener.contextInitialized(MangoContextListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set up the connection to the database in context.xml (configuration file tomcat7) the example below.

You should copy the files: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar", "mysql-connector-java-3.1.8-bin.jar" to the directory "./tomcat7/lib"

The example of configuration file context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application --><Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="jdbc/scadalts"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          testOnReturn="false"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="30000"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
          maxActive="80"
          minIdle="10"
          maxWait="10000"
          initialSize="10"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="1000"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          abandonWhenPercentageFull="75"
          logAbandoned="true"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
          jmxEnabled="true"
          jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
                                                        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;
                                                        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer;
                                                        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=1500)"
          username="root"
          password="root"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scadalts"
         />

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

</Context>
```

It should works.

In above configuration software required server installed MySql database "scadalts" and the root user with the password root on localhost.

Comment: Configurations can change and adjust to own environment.